# Find maximum value for each row

Tags: mysql

Here is the simplified version of my question. There are two tables one has machines and the second has their info about their state change with date reference(not actualy the date, but the shift index, that's why I have to make another query to get the date itself).
I want to get the last state of each machine.
My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM machines  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM statechange, dates WHERE....ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS state
ON state.mid=machines.mid
```

But I get only one machine as a result of the query. 
How can I do it without creating a view?

Comment: What is the primary key of the `statechange` table?

Comment: How are statechange and dates joined? You appear to be using a join via where clause but you do not mention the joining columns.

Comment: is is not date in fact, it is date's index...date table has several fields including the date, that's how the statechange and date are joined.

Comment: @lvil - So there is a single (multiple?) foreign key column (which is not the date column) in the `dates` table that points to the primary key column in the statechange table?

Comment: @lvil - Btw, something else that is not clear, does the `date` column come from the `statechange` table or the `dates` table? If it comes from the `dates` table, then solution you marked as an answer does not include this join. If it does come from the statechange table, why have the join to dates at all?

Comment: @Thomas - If I understand you correctly, the opposite of what you have just written. Primary in date table is foreign in statechange

Comment: @lvil - This is why showing us some schema is useful. What about the date column? Is that from the statechange table or the dates table?

Comment: @Thomas - I used the so called date table because there is some other information on the date. it is kond of a shift I think

Comment: @lvil - So does that mean the date column you are using to determine "last" is from the statechange table or the dates table?

Comment: @Thomas - from the dates table, that is why I have to make the subquery.

Comment: @lvil - Ok. Then it should be noted that the solution you marked as the answer does not account for this important detail. You should note this detail about the date column in your question either by stating that fact or by adding an alias to the date column in your query (i.e., `statechange.date`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select m.*,s.`date` from machines as m
inner join (
select mid,`date`
from statechange
order by `date` desc) as s
on m.mid = s.mid
group by m.mid
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly in my case, but how can I be sure that I get the last state? Or is it a property of the GROUP BY?

Comment: group by clause retrieves the first record that it finds. Since dates are in descending order you're sure that you'll get your desired records.

Comment: Is an Order By clause even allowed in an derived table when you aren't using Limit? What would that even mean?

Comment: As Thomas asked, I fully agree with him as this is not the full answer though it gave me the direction and the main logic

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the primary key of the `statechange` table is something on which Max makes sense (like an integer)

```
Select ...
From Machines As M
    Left Join   (
                Select S1.mid, Max( S1.PrimaryKeyCol ) As PrimaryKeyCol
                From statechange As S1
                    Join dates As D1
                        On D1.statechangeFK = S1.PrimaryKeyCol
                Where D1.date = (
                                Select Max( D2.date )
                                From dates As D2
                                Where D2.statechangeFK = D1.statechangeFK
                                )
                Group By S1.mid
                ) As LastStateChange
        On LastStateChange.mid = M.mid

    Left Join statechange As S
        On S.PrimaryKeyCol = LastStateChange.PrimaryKeyCol
```

The last join is in case you want to return columns from the statechange table.

---

**Revision based on additional info**

```
Select ...
From Machines As M
    Left Join   (
                Select S1.mid, Max( S1.PrimaryKeyCol ) As PrimaryKeyCol
                From dates As D1
                    Join statechange As S1
                        On S1.DatesForeignKeyCol = D1.PrimaryKeyCol
                Where D1.date = (
                                Select Max( D2.date )
                                From dates As D2
                                    Join statechange As S2
                                        On S2.DatesForeignKeyCol = D2.PrimaryKeyCol
                                Where S2.mid = S1.mid
                                )
                Group By S1.mid
                ) As LastStateChange
        On LastStateChange.mid = M.mid

    Left Join statechange As S
        On S.PrimaryKeyCol = LastStateChange.PrimaryKeyCol

    Left Join dates As D
        On D.PrimaryKeyCol = S.DatesForeignKeyCol
```

One of the reasons I used the above approach is to account for the scenario where you might have multiple `statechange` rows for the same `mid` and `date` value. The above approach will use the primary key column as the tie-breaker in that scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have thought about all the possible cases and my real query is much longer.

Answer (score 1):

You get the latest statechange for every machine by doing something like this.

```
SELECT mid, max(date)
FROM statechange
GROUP BY mid
```

Then you join on that to get the current state for every machine. (Guessing at column names.)

```
SELECT m.*, sc.state, sc.date
FROM machines m
INNER JOIN statechange sc 
    ON ( sc.mid = m.mid )
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT mid, MAX(date) date
            FROM statechange
            GROUP BY mid 
            ) s
    ON ( (s.mid = sc.mid) and (s.date = sc.date) );
```

I think a view for the current state of every machine might be widely useful, though.